# Working with python resource file

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, resources, bundle

I have added a python executable resource file using the following method:

http://irwinkwan.com/2013/04/29/python-executables-pyinstaller-and-a-48-hour-game-design-compo/

Everything works fine, but the only problem is that the resource file is being unpacked every time I am running my application - the file size is almost 5mb and it increases the application initialization time unnecessarily. So the question is - is it possible to unpack the resource in the certain moment with python?

Maybe there are any other methods of bundling the files resources in Python?